# How to integrate bessel function with variable bounds?

Tags: python, variables, math, scipy, numerical-integration

In short I am trying to plot this function:
[F(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdHgs.png)
which is an integration with a variable limit.
My code so far is:

```
import scipy
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(0,6,1000)

def bessel(z): return scipy.special.kv(5/3,z)
def F(x): return x * scipy.integrate.quad(bessel(x),x,np.inf)

plt.loglog(X,F(X))
```

with an error that says "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous."
I've done this same integration in matlab, and the solution was to use "arrayfun" is there a similar function in python that applies F(x) to every element of X?

Comment: At least you should have `def F(x): return x * scipy.integrate.quad(bessel, x, np.inf)` a reference to the function, not its call.

Comment: Show the FULL error message.  Read the `quad` docs, paying close attention to what it expects for arguments. Don't just wing it based your matlab exlerience.

Comment: You are trying to integrate a function using the same variable as bound. That is mathematically very problematic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446591/why-is-it-considered-incorrect-to-use-the-variable-of-integration-as-a-boundary